# Bluetooth connectionless mode on Android

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I am using Android 4.x and would like to send some data connectionless. I tried the Android API (BluetoothSocket) but it's only possible to send data if the device is connected. Is there a possibility to send data connectionless? This should be possible since BluetoothV3.0.
Thanks.

Comment: how would u send data without making any connection?

Comment: I don't think Android supports L2CAP-less connections, that would pose security holes. Anyways, bluetooth-connectionless was always intended for `small` amounts of data.

Comment: I also want to know that broadcasting message is possible or not in Android apps. Is @Levente Kurusa 's comment is the correct answer for this question?